# Aligning html input fields and their label to center of page

Tags: html, css, input, label

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TB7i.png)I am trying to align a bunch of input fields and their respective labels to the center of html page. Please look at the 2 images I've attached. The 1st one shows what I am aiming to achieve and the 2nd one shows how far I've gotten. My html code is fine however, I am not able to figure out the CSS code to make this happen. Below is the css code that has gotten me close the goal (pic 1). The part that I need help with is the CSS code pertaining to the form label and form input aspects.

---

```
body{

background-color: white;
}
#container{
background-color: lightblue;
width: 60%;
height: 700px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top:50px;
text-align: center; 
padding-top: 1px;
}
#form{
background-color: whitesmoke;
width: 90%;
heigth:auto;
text-align: center;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:10px;

}
#form label{
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
display: inline-block;
text-align:justify-all;

}
#form input{  
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: justify;

}
```

Comment: Please add images and HTML code you tried

Comment: Hi - just added an image of the survey form I am trying to build. Again, I know how to do everything except get the input fields and their label to align along an imaginary vertical line.

Comment: where is the 2 image?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to align input fields at the center, the simplest way is to use `margin : 0 auto;` CSS property.
Please find below code reference:

```css
div.container {
  width: 300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background: lightblue
}

input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
  margin : 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <input type='text' name='sample' value='sample'>
  </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot the label

Comment: Hi - thanks for responding but it didn't solve the issue. The main issue is that I have 6 input fields of various types and each input field has it's own label. Each input field and it's label is on individual lines. The problem is I cannot figure out how to get the input fields to align along a vertical line and their labels to also align along the same vertical line. Let me see if I can attach image of what I am trying to do.